React TypeScript Search Bar centering off the wrong starting point and overlapping issues
I have the following React (TypeScript) page:
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import ScreenComponent from '../components/screens/ScreenComponent';
import PanelComponent from '../components/panels/PanelComponent';

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ScreenComponent>
      <PanelComponent width={30} title="Panel 1">
        <Typography variant="h6">Panel 1 - 30% width</Typography>
      </PanelComponent>
      <PanelComponent width={60} title="Panel 2">
        <Typography variant="h6">Panel 2 - 60% width</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h6">Panel 2 - 60% width</Typography>
      </PanelComponent>
    </ScreenComponent>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;

This uses the following Header.css:
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 8vh;
    background-color: #1a242a;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.header-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.shield-icon {
    height: 40px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.header-text {
    color: #acb3a1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.header-search-bar {
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.search-bar-input {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #aab3a1;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 60px;
}

.search-bar-input::placeholder {
    color: white;
}

.search-bar-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.enter-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    color: white;
}

An the following Header.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import { TextField, InputAdornment } from '@mui/material';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import KeyboardReturnIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardReturn';
import shieldIcon from '../assets/shub-shield.png';
import CircleNotificationsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CircleNotifications';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header-content">
        <img src={shieldIcon} alt="MyApp Shield" className="shield-icon" />
        <span className="header-text">MyApp</span>
      </div>

      <div className="header-search-bar">
        <TextField
          placeholder="Search"
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <SearchIcon className="search-bar-icon" />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <KeyboardReturnIcon className="enter-icon" />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            style: {
              backgroundColor: '#aab3a1',
              borderRadius: '25px',
              border: '2px solid #aab3a1',
              color: '#1a242a',
              width: '100%',
              paddingLeft: '10px',
            },
          }}
          className="search-bar-input"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="header-notification-icon">
        <CircleNotificationsIcon style={{ color: '#aab3a1', fontSize: 40 }} />
      </div>

      <div className="header-menu-icon">
        <MenuIcon style={{ color: '#aab3a1', fontSize: 40 }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;

I'm struggling with the Search Bar at the top of the page header.The Search Bar is appearing centered between the header-context div (basically a logo and some text) on the left, and the two icons (notifications and menu) on the right.
Instead, I want the Search Bar centered in the middle of the screen, regardless of what content exists to the left and right of it. Meaning, if the header-content is wider than the 2 icons, its OK for the Search Bar to appear closer to the header-context and for there to be more space in between the Search Bar and the 2 icons on the far right of it. All that matters is that the Search Bar is universally centered.
Also, you'll notice that the text inside the Search Bar is superimposed underneath the SearchIcon. If there's any way to push that out so that the SearchIcon always appears to the left of the search text, I'd appreciate that as well. Can anyone see where I'm going awry?
Update
I have added a padding-right declaration to my .search-bar-input rule:
.search-bar-input {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #aab3a1;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

But the search icon problem persists.

For this, add position: absolute; to .header-search-bar and position: relative; to .header then make it 50% from left then to ensure it is perfectly centered add  transform: translateX(-50%);.
.header-search-bar {
     width: 40%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 0 auto;
     left:50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
}

Now for ensuring Icons doesn't overlap the text input add padding left and right to search-bar-input
Update
See this codesandbox example from mui which is similar to what you want
Hope this helps...

Thanks @Jaiyash (+1) -- please see my edits regarding the overlapping Icon and search text. I added padding-right: 60px; and that doesn't seem to change anything. Thanks again!

I have added a code sandbox link see this
